# How to use location biasing (nearby) for GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions?

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-api, google-play-services, google-places-api

I'm using the GoogleApiClient and Places API through Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions() to get address/place autocomplete suggestions (https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete).  The method requires a GoogleApiClient object, a String to autocomplete, and a LatLngBounds object to limit the search range.  This is what my usage looks like:

```
PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
    Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(googleApiClient, constraint.toString(), bounds, filter);
```

According to the documentation, the bounds parameter is required.  But when I look at the webservice version (https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete#location_biasing) I see a lot more parameters that can be used including location and radius for location biasing.

Is it possible to do the same thing for getAutocompletePredictions() method or do I have to write my own code to hit the webservice, supply the api key, and parse the response?  Using GeoDataApi seems convenient because it handles a lot of those details, but I haven't been able to find a good way to easily limit its search range in a smart way.  Seems like this be a fairly common scenario, so there must be some widely accepted pattern or solution for this that I just haven't been able to find yet.

Answer (score 1):

`GeoDataApi` does seem to be a bit limited at the moment.  If you choose to go outside of Google Play Services, you could take a look at the [Sprockets for Android](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android) library (I'm the developer), which provides a complete Java interface for the Google Places API (see [Sprockets for Java](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets)).  Sprockets also includes a [GooglePlaceAutoComplete](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.html) widget, [GooglePlacesLoader](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/content/GooglePlacesLoader.html), and a [GooglePlacesAdapter](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlacesAdapter.html), in case those might be useful for you.